# Assembly - Some problems in the macro

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I've a assembly program as below.

```
;=======================
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 100h

putchar MACRO char
    label:
    mov dl, char
    mov ah, 2
    int 21h
ENDM
.CODE
    MAIN Proc
         putchar  'A'
         putchar  'S'
         putchar  'M'
         mov ah, 4ch
         int 21h
    MAIN ENDP
```

My program won't compile.

P/S: Can't modify the `putchar` macro.

Comment: How about an error message? Also, what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely your problem is that the `label:` label in the macro is being defined multiple times (each expansion of the macro). You need to either remove the label (there's really no reason for it being there), or use a local label. Search for "local label" on this page: http://webster.cs.ucr.edu/Page_TechDocs/MASMDoc/ProgrammersGuide/Chap_09.htm.

If you can't modify the `putchar` macro, then I don't see how you can make this code compile.

Comment: Yes, I added Local directive into 'putchar' macro inside my program, it's worked. Thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

You cant use Label like that in macro
You need to use local label

```
 putchar MACRO char
    local label
    label:
    mov dl, char
    mov ah, 2
    int 21h
    ENDM
```

because it copy the macro code to your code 
not like proc that take you to another ip 
the macro just copy the code so you cant make a same name label twice ... its compiler error so use the local